# Cannot insert data into Oracle table by python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am going to insert data into a table which is in Oracle using by python. It did not give me any error but also it did not insert anything into my table in Oracle SQL Developer. Also I wrote a query to get select rom my table in python environment it gave me output.

My `CREATE TABLE` code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE INSERT_TEST(FISRT_COLUMN VARCHAR2(30),SECOND_COLUMN NUMBER(10,2))")
```

My `INSERT` code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

data = [
('Mina', 20),
('Minoo', 32),
('Sara', 22),
('Ehssan', 25),
('Ladan', 55)
]

for row in data:
     cursor.execute("""
          insert into INSERT_TEST (FISRT_COLUMN, SECOND_COLUMN)
          values (:1, :2)""", row)
```

My `SELECT` query:

```
re = cursor.execute("select * from INSERT_TEST")

for row in re:
    print(row)
```

My output in python environment:

`('Mina', 20.0) ('Minoo', 32.0) ('Sara', 22.0) ('Ehssan', 25.0) ('Ladan', 55.0)`

My output in Oracle SQL Developer is empty!

Comment: [Oracle SQL Developer is a free, **integrated development environment**](https://www.oracle.com/ru/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html). Table is not present in IDE, it is a database object. To make your changes persistent in SQL you need to commit at the end of your session.

Comment: I put  `commit;` that before but it gives me `name 'commit' is not defined` error.

Comment: Apart from the issue you'd better to use [`cursor.executemany(stmt, list)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) instead of loop as it is pythonic and faster

Comment: But your code doesn't contain `commit`

Comment: here no, I said before. I delete commit; it gave me error also I wrote the error, then I delete this and ask my problem here.

Comment: Then you still have to commit, but with the [correct syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit)

Comment: [Frist](https://thedailywtf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `conn.commit()` at the end of your program. `commit` belongs to the `connection` class, not to the `cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for your database driver.

- For some database drivers, the default behaviour is to `COMMIT` any uncommitted  data when you close the transaction and the connection; so, make sure you close the connection when you have finished.
- For other database drivers, the default behaviour is to `ROLLBACK` any uncommitted data when you close the transaction and the connection; in this case, you will need to explicitly `COMMIT` the data before you close the connection otherwise it will `ROLLBACK` your changes.

The Oracle database does not let other sessions (even belonging to the same user) see uncommitted data so, if you `INSERT` from Python but do not `COMMIT` (either explicitly or, if the driver supports it, implicitly when you close the connection) then you will be able to see it from the Python session where you created the data but it will be hidden when you view it in another session (i.e. from SQL Developer).

Answer (score 0):

I understand it depends on table in oracle SQL developer, a the end of my code I have to write `cursor.execute('commit')` to show that it end and insert all of the data into my table.